# Как привязать DataGrid к xml файлу

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

Как можно связать DataGrid с xml файлом, что мы можно было добавлять\удалять\редактировать данные и сохранять их в xml документе? Xml выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Settings>
  <Element>
    <Checked>True</Checked>
    <TextData>some text</TextData>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <Checked>False</Checked>
    <TextData>another text</TextData>
  </Element>
</Settings>
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350" Width="525">

    <DockPanel Margin="10">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" TextElement.FontSize="18">
            <Button Content="Добавить" Margin="0,0,0,5" Padding="5"/>
            <Button Content="Удалить" Margin="0,5" Padding="5" />
        </StackPanel>

        <DataGrid Name="DataGrid" Margin="0,0,5,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" Header="Checked"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" Header="TextData"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: [`XmlDataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) пробовали?

Comment: [Тут][1] во втором ответе есть пример с биндингом к xml-файлу


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/220808/c-спарсить-xml?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=221336#221336

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы связать xml файл и DataGrid воспользуйтесь XLinq.

Пример:
Во вью модели или в коде вьюшки:

```
var elements = XElement.Load("List.xml");
myGridView.DataContext = elements;
```

В Xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[Element]}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="IsChecked" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Checked].Value}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="TextData" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[TextData].Value}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```